# How can I add apply button to filter in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, angular2-custom-pipes

Currently, I have a Gender and Impact filter to the table which is able to filter the data on option selected.

*For e.g. If you will select Male it will filter male data and the same for female, impact: applicable and not applicable.*

Now, I wanted to add an apply button that will join both of them together and filter. Once clicked on the apply button that will filter data combination of both.

[image]

[image]

Can anyone please help me with the requirement?

Code:

```
<div class="filter-data clearfix">
    <form #form="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group float-left mr-4">
        <strong>Gender</strong>
        <br>
        <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="gender" ngModel>
          <option></option>
          <option value="Male">Male</option>
          <option value="Female">Female</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group float-left">
        <strong>Impact</strong>
        <br>
        <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="impact" ngModel>
          <option></option>
          <option value="Applicable">Applicable</option>
          <option value="Not Applicable">Not Applicable</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group float-left mt-4 ml-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mr-2">Apply</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

<table class="table table-sm table-responsive">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <input type="checkbox" name="allNonTrades" (change)="selectAllClicked($event)">
          </th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Gender</th>
          <th>DOB</th>
          <th>Impact</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="record-row" (click)="viewUser(user)" *ngFor="let user of allUser | tableFilter: form.value | paginate: { id: 'listing_pagination', itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: page, totalItems: totalRecords }">
          <td><input *ngIf="!isEdit"  name="nontrades" [checked]="user.selected" (change)="changeTradesByCategory($event)" [(ngModel)]="user.checked" type="checkbox" (change)="checkboxClicked()"></td>
          <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
          <td>{{user.last_name}}</td>
          <td>{{user.email}}</td>
          <td>{{user.gender}}</td>
          <td>{{user.dob}}</td>
          <td>{{user.impact}}</td>
          <td>
            <button *ngIf="!isEdit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="editUser(user)">Edit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-sm ml-2" (click)="deleteUser(user)">Delete</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

table-filter.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'tableFilter'
})

export class TableFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(list: any[], filters: Object) {
    const keys = Object.keys(filters).filter(key => filters[key]);
    const filterUser = user => keys.every(key => user[key] === filters[key]);
    return keys.length ? list.filter(filterUser) : list;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add **[ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'submit'}"** in gender and impact select tags. This let `form.value` to update only on submit and thus changing `tableFilter: form.value` and filter is applied accordingly.

```
<select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="gender" ngModel [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'submit'}">


<select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="impact" ngModel [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'submit'}">
```

Lastly change Apply Button type to **submit**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mr-2">Apply</button>
```

Comment: I wanted to bring one more filter as a date range.

 `<select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="impact" ngModel [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'submit'}">
          <option></option>
          <option value="">01/01/1987 - 31/12/1987</option>
          <option value="">01/01/2000 - 31/12/2020</option>
        </select>` 

How can I make that data filter to show DOB results matching that range?

Comment: can you please help me what changes do I need to make in my table-filter.pipe so, that it will show the results matching that range?

Comment: const filterUser = user => keys.every(key => user[key] === filters[key]); here u have to do the changes.

Comment: I am not very good in this. It would be really helpful if you can spend few more mins and do I change as I don't know what changes do I have do.

Comment: Try this`const filterUser = user => keys.every(key => { if(key == 'dob') {const sDate=new Date(user[key].split(' - ')[0]); const eDate=new Date(user[key].split(' - ')[1]); const date = new Date(user[key]); return  date > sDate && date< eDate } else{ return user[key] === filters[key]}  })`and Change select for DOB name='dob'

Comment: what would be the value in options? `<select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="dob" ngModel [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'submit'}">
          <option></option>
          <option value="01/01/1987 - 31/12/1987">01/01/1987 - 31/12/1987</option>
          <option value="01/01/1987 - 31/12/1987">01/01/2000 - 31/12/2020</option>
        </select>`

Comment: I am getting in the console as an Invalid date for sDate, eDate

Comment: I tried `<input type="date" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="dob" ngModel [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'submit'}">
        <input type="date" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="dob" ngModel [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'submit'}">` but no luck

Comment: Done changes select to input type date Min & Max for date Range and changed TableFilterPipe. Check [StackBlitz][1] link.Lost actual asked in question link so adding here.

  
[1]: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mriubn?file=src/app/table-filter.pipe.ts

Comment: If I am selecting the same date in start date n end date it's not showing up the result to me https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mriubn?file=src/app/table-filter.pipe.ts for e.g. 01/01/1987